# Image caching in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, image-caching

If I do

```
rowBackground = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottomCell2.png"]
```

the image is cached for the entire life cycle of the app or reloaded and recached everytime I execute that instruction (in other views or part of the app)?

I do that in every tableview of my app. Is it efficient?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the reference of `+imageNamed:`:

> This method looks in the system caches for an image object with the
>   specified name and returns that object if it exists. If a matching
>   image object is not already in the cache, this method loads the image
>   data from the specified file, caches it, and then returns the
>   resulting object.

Cache is efficient, but eats memory. If your table view contains large amount of images, the memory may burn up. So you may consider `+imageWithContentsOfFile:` or other similar methods to load image.

Comment: My tableView only loads 3 types of images so I think the +imageNamed: approach is way better. Thanks!